# How can i wait for multiple signals on same channel in temporal golang

Tags: go, temporal-workflow

I have a slice in my workflow and need to wait until i receive a signal for each element in the slice, on the same signal channel. I tried using the following code but it does not seem to wait on all the messages being received.

```
        selector := workflow.NewSelector(ctx)
        notificationSignalChan := workflow.GetSignalChannel(ctx, "my-channel")

        for i := 0; i < len(container.Items); i++ {
            if container.Items[i].Status != status.Pending {
                continue
            }

            var expectedNotification events.Notification

            selector.AddReceive(notificationSignalChan, func(c workflow.ReceiveChannel, more bool) {
                // So it has to be explicitly consumed here
                c.Receive(ctx, &expectedNotification)
                idx := slices.IndexFunc(container.Items, func(item *model.Item) bool {
                    return item.ID == notification.ItemID
                })
                
                recordedAt := workflow.Now(ctx)
                container.Items[idx].Status = status.Processed
                err = workflow.ExecuteActivity(ctx, activities.OnProcessed, container.Items[idx]).Get(ctx, nil)
                
                if err != nil {
                    panic(err)
                }
            })
        }
        
        for i := 0; i < len(container.Items); i++ {
            if container.Items[i].Status != status.Pending {
                continue
            }

            selector.Select(ctx)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a endless loop and a select statement so when ever you got an object from channel just compare with your items on list and remove that item from your list, check if there is any item in list continue else just break the for loop.

```
for {
    select {
    case data := <-signal:
        for idx, obj := range lst {
            if data == obj {
                // do your staff
                fmt.Println(data)

                // remove that item from list
                if len(lst) <= 1 {
                    return
                }
                lst = append(lst[:idx], lst[idx+1:]...)
                // break the inner loop
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```